# Why is my CPU doing matrix operations faster than GPU instead?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu, mxnet

When I tried to verify that the GPU does matrix operations over the CPU, I got unexpected results.CPU performs better than GPU according to my experience result, it makes me confused.

I used cpu and gpu to do matrix multiplication respectively.Programming environment is MXNet and cuda-10.1.

with gpu:

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import nd
x = nd.random.normal(shape=(100000,100000),ctx=mx.gpu())
y = nd.random.normal(shape=(100000,100000),ctx=mx.gpu())
%timeit nd.dot(x,y)
```

> 50.8 µs ± 1.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

with cpu:

```
x1 = nd.random.normal(shape=(100000,100000),ctx=mx.cpu())
y1 = nd.random.normal(shape=(100000,100000),ctx=mx.cpu())
%timeit nd.dot(x1,y1)
```

> 33.4 µs ± 1.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Why CPU faster？ My CPU model is i5-6300HQ and GPU model is Nividia GTX 950M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: Your matrix multiplication is actually not running :)**

MXNet is an asynchronous framework that piles work requests in a queue treated asynchronously on a need-to-run basis by its execution engine. So what you're measuring is only the time it took to send the request, not to execute it. That's why it is so small (microseconds on a 100k*100k matrix would be surprisingly fast) and roughly equal for both CPU and GPU. To force execution, you need to add a call that forces production of a result, for example a `print` or a `nd.dot(x, y).wait_to_read()`. See here a code very similar to your benchmark https://github.com/ThomasDelteil/MXNetParisWorkshop/blob/master/FromNDArrayToTrainedModel.ipynb

Extra comments:

1. **The gain of using GPU vs CPU comes with the size of the
   parallelism opportunity**. On simple tasks, that gain can be small to
   non existent. CPU core frequencies are actually 2 to 3 times bigger
   than GPU frequencies (your i5-6300HQ does 2.3GHz with 3.2GHz boost
   ability while your GTX 950M does 0.9GHz with 1.1GHz boost ability).
2. **MXNet ndarray is very fast at matrix algebra on CPU**, because (1) its asynchronous paradigm optimizes the order of computation (2) its C++ backend runs things in parallel and (3) I believe the default MXNet build comes with Intel MKL, which significantly boosts algebra capacities of Intel CPUs
   (https://medium.com/apache-mxnet/mxnet-boosts-cpu-performance-with-mkl-dnn-b4b7c8400f98). Its ability to run compute on GPU within the same API is also a big strength over Numpy for example.
3. I don't think your test will run on GPU: instantiating such a big matrix on
   an NVIDIA Tesla V100 (16GB men, 4x more than a GTX 950M) runs in a
   "large tensor size error"

Comment: As you suggested, I use nd.dot(x,y).wait_to_read and change the matrix shape to 1000*1000，It can be seen from the result that the GPU requires less time than my CPU.thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the module you're using but your CPU can access your memory way quicker and also saves a lot of stuff in cache. Your GPU has longer times to load the data into GPU memory and also takes longer to be called from your CPU.
Thats always the downside of GPU computation. When you can load a bunch of data into GPU memory, there's a good chance of being faster.
Btw, thats why deep learning frameworks work in batches. When you can't work with batches, I'd always use the CPU. You also got some potential for performance improvements with multiprocessing.

Comment: thank you first. But as you can see, x and y, x1 and y1 already exist in CPU/GPU memory after the first two codes are executed,so I think I only timed the matrix multiplication operation,loading time is not included.

Comment: this is not the root cause in that case, see my answer below :)